# Broker that allows algo trading, no pdt rule and a low minimum deposit

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading, broker

I was looking for a broker that offers these things:

```
1. API for performing transactions from a script
2. No PDT rule
3. Low minimum deposit for a margin account (Able to short)
```

But I could not find any others than IB, which requires you to have at least 25.000$  in equities to surpass the PDT rule. A little help finding some brokers would be appriciated.

> I am a non-US resident as well.
>
> Asset class: Stock

Comment: What asset class are you looking to trade?

Comment: @HamishGibson Stocks

Answer (score 2):

PDT ([Pattern Day Trader](https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answerspatterndaytraderhtm.html)) is an SEC rule.  You will not find a US retail broker anywhere that allows you to surpass it.

If you were a professional with the proper licenses and had an account at a proprietary trading firm the rule could be surpassed.  Here is a recent list of firms compiled by someone else.  It is by no means comprehensive but maybe try contacting some of them: [Proprietary Trading Firms](https://www.traderslog.com/proprietarytradingfirms)

Comment: http://www.tradezero.co does not follow the PDT rule.

Comment: @EliasKnudsen I edited my answer.  PDT only apply's to US brokers.

Comment: Do know of any non-US retail broker that meet my criterias?

Comment: @EliasKnudsen The link in my answer includes some firms have European offices.  I would try contacting them and see if they can accommodate you.

Comment: Have you looked at Saxo Bank, Degiro Online Stock Trading, SwissQuote, Lynx. I don't really know these and am not recommending any of them.